# Why did my Charmander egg hatch to shiny Wynaut? Is this a daycare feature?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

The other night I stopped Masuda breeding and started to breed a few duplicates of starters with my Japanese Ditto, in the hopes of trading them on the GTS for other starters. I bred Charmander, Cyndaquill, and Fennekin and obtain all three of their eggs.

Here's where it gets weird: the first egg that hatches is the Charmander egg... but it didn't hatch a Charmander... it hatched a shiny Wynaut instead! Both of the other eggs hatched the expected starter.

I've never owned a Wynaut or it's evolution, plus the egg goes into your team once you take it from the caretaker. And that's why I'm really confused!

I've asked a few of my friends and they've got no clue what happened... I'm definitely psyched to have gotten a 1/4000+ chance outcome on my first (nonintentional) attempt. But can you tell me if this is indeed a feature of the daycare system?

Update: Upon request, here is the Wynaut summary screen:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you received the Wynaut egg from the NPC in Lavaridge Town? I'm pretty sure that is not shiny locked (i.e. it can be shiny when hatched)

Comment: @Robotnik that must be it :)

Comment: @Robotnik Thanks for finding the answer to my mix-up, I must have misclicked when organizing my boxes or something. I guess that's what happens when you dont play a game in 3-4 years, you just dont remember when things happened where. And I probably bet I never picked up the charmander egg in the first place. Anyway thanks for all the input, and I guess I just got wicked lucky with that egg too huh.

Comment: @ValicFair - haha no problem, glad to help out, and yeah super lucky! Congratulations :)

Answer (score 15):

There is no 'random-shiny-baby' factor at all in the Pokemon daycare. As Robotnik♦ suggested (and your image now confirms), you obtained the egg from the [elderly lady in Lavaridge Town](https://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire/Lavaridge_Town).

Even though, congratulations on the shiny Wynaut!